# establish theisomorphism between the equivalence classes of ideals and binary quadratic forms of discriminant $d$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Definitions

An integer $n$ is represented by the binary quadratic form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$
if there exist
integers $r$ and $s$ such that $n=ar^2 + brs + cs^2$

we call these two forms equivalent and, in general, binary
quadratic form f is equivalent to $F(X, Y ) = f(\alpha X + \beta Y, \gamma X + \delta Y )$ whenever $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are
integers with $\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1$ ,and so $f$ and $F$ represent the same integers. Therefore to
determine what numbers are represented by a given binary quadratic form, we can study
any binary quadratic form in the same equivalence class. If $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$
and $F(X, Y ) = AX^2 + BXY + CY^2$
above, note that $A = f(\alpha, \gamma), C = f(\beta, \delta)$ and
$B^2 − 4AC = b^2 − 4ac$ $($in fact $B - b = 2(a \alpha \beta + b\beta \gamma + c\gamma \delta)$.
For now I will focus on the case where the discriminant $d \ 0$ (since it is easier), $\\$
First note that if $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$
then $4af(x, y) = (2ax + by)^2 +|d|y^2$
and so is either always positive (if $a > 0$), else always negative. Replacing $f$ by $−f$ in
the latter case we develop the theory of positive definite quadratic forms, and one can then
easily deduce all the analogous results for negative definite $f$.

$\\$.
 The integers represented by the quadratic form gf(x, y)
are of the form gn where n is represented by gf(x, y), so we assume that gcd(a, b, c) = 1.
Gauss observed that it is possible to find a unique reduced binary quadratic form in
each equivalence class, that is with
 $−a < b \leq a < c$   or    $0 \leq b \leq a = c.$

Given any Binary Quadratic Form we can reduce it using Gauss Algorithm.

If $d \equiv 0 or 1 (mod 4)$ and is squarefree other than perhaps a factor of $4$
or $8$, then we say that $d$ is a fundamental discriminant. An algebraic integer is a number
that is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients; the algebraic integers in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ take the form $ \mathbb{Z}[\tau_d] :=  \{ m + n\tau_d : m, n ∈ \mathbb{Z} \} $, where
$\tau_d= $\begin{cases}
       \text{$\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}$,} &\quad\text{if $d \equiv 0 (mod 4)$}\\
       \text{$\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$,} &\quad\text{if $d \equiv 1 (mod 4)$} 
     \end{cases}

How do I establish theisomorphism between the equivalence classes of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\tau_d]$ presented in the form $\left(2a,b+\sqrt{d}\right)$ where $4a$ divides $b^2-d$, and binary quadratic forms of discriminant $d$